# Retrieving an image with Retrofit sent as raw binary string

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to get image from server. Originally image is sent this way

```
                val file = uri.toFile()
                val fileBody = file.asRequestBody("image/png".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                val filePart = createFormData("file", file.name, fileBody)
```

In request it looks like this [image]

When I try to get image like this

```
                        val fileContents = state.data.toByteArray()
                        val filename = "avatar.png"
                        requireContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
                            it.write(fileContents)
                        }
```

it becomes malformed

How should I properly save image?

Answer (score 0):

Try `File("/path/avatar.png").writeBytes(fileContents)`